# How to make a method available to all controllers? And how to all models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails and have written a method `to_csv` which I have put it in products_controller.rb, but I want it to available to all other controllers too. What is the preferred way to do that? Is it in application.rb?

Similarly, if I am writing a method in some model.rb, how to share that method between all the models?

Answer (score 6):

application_controller will be the place. If for model, maybe you can write in a module, then 
include in your model which you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a separate model without inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` and define your csv method in that particular model. And from any controller just call

```
model_name.method_name(parameters)
```

For example, in the model CsvDB:

```
class CsvDB
  def export(parameters)  
    # your csv logic goes here  
  end
end
```

From any controller just call

```
CsvDB.export(parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Try ActiveRecord::Base monkeypatching. 
The initializer directory is a best place to collect all those little task

So, try /config/initializers/active_record_extension.rb,

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.export(parameters)
     #your csv logic goes here
   end
end
```

or

2) create master class, which is used to inherit by all active_record model

for example /models/your_class.rb

```
class YourClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.export(parameters)
     #your csv logic goes here
  end
end

class CsvDB < YourClass
end
```

Comment: @Mischa Yes that is fine. but If we use monkeypatch, no need to include/extend modules manually to all models